# How do I navigate a structure array and also read/write to it?

Tags: c, image, debugging

I have tried fread((*pArr)[i][j], sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file); and also tried using pointer arithmetic to the best of my understanding but I have been unsuccessful in implementing my writePixelsBMP and readPixelsBMP to do anything more spam the first incorrect pixels. Here is my whole code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct BMP_Header {
    char signature[2];
  int size;
  short reserved1;
  short reserved2;
  int offset_pixel_array;
};

struct DIB_Header{
    int  size;
  int width;
  int height;
  short planes;
  short bits_per_pixel;
  int compression;
  int image_size;
  int x_per_meter;
  int y_per_meter;
  int colors_in_table;
  int important_colors;
};

struct Pixel{
    unsigned char r;
  unsigned char b;
  unsigned char g;
};
void readBMPHeader(FILE* file, struct BMP_Header* header) {
  fread(&header->signature, sizeof(char) *2, 1,file);
  fread(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->reserved1, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fread(&header->reserved2, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fread(&header->offset_pixel_array, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void readDIBHeader(FILE* file, struct DIB_Header* header) {
  fread(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->width, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->height, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->planes, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fread(&header->bits_per_pixel, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fread(&header->compression, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->image_size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->x_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->y_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->colors_in_table, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fread(&header->important_colors, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void readPixelsBMP(FILE* file, int width, int height, struct Pixel (**pArr)[width][height]) {
    *pArr = malloc( sizeof(struct Pixel[width][height]) );
    if (*pArr == NULL) {
        printf("Error! Insufficient memory!");
        return;
    }

    int padding = (4 - ((3*width) % 4)) % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            fread(*pArr, sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file);
        }
        if (padding) {
                fseek(file, padding, SEEK_CUR);
            }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
void writeBMPHeader(FILE* file, struct BMP_Header* header) {
  fwrite(&header->signature, sizeof(char) *2, 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->reserved1, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->reserved2, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->offset_pixel_array, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void writeDIBHeader(FILE* file, struct DIB_Header* header) {
  fwrite(&header->size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->width, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->height, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->planes, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->bits_per_pixel, sizeof(short), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->compression, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->image_size, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->x_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->y_per_meter, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->colors_in_table, sizeof(int), 1,file);
  fwrite(&header->important_colors, sizeof(int), 1,file);
}
void writePixelsBMP(FILE* file, int width, int height, struct Pixel (**pArr)[width][height]) {
    int padding = (4 - ((3*width) % 4)) % 4;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            fwrite(*pArr, sizeof(struct Pixel), 1, file);
        }
        if (padding)
            fwrite("0", sizeof(char),padding, file);
    }
    char eof = 0x00;
    fwrite(&eof, sizeof(char), 1, file);
}

int main() {
    char* filename = "test1wonderbread.bmp";
    char* output = "test2wonderbread.bmp";
    FILE* file_input = fopen(filename, "rb");
    FILE* file_output = fopen(output, "wb");

    struct BMP_Header* header = (struct BMP_Header*) malloc(sizeof(struct BMP_Header));
    readBMPHeader(file_input, header);
    struct DIB_Header* dib_header = (struct DIB_Header*) malloc(sizeof(struct DIB_Header));
    readDIBHeader(file_input, dib_header);

    struct Pixel (*pArr)[dib_header->width][dib_header->height];
    readPixelsBMP(file_input, dib_header->width, dib_header->height, &pArr);

    writeBMPHeader(file_output, header);
    writeDIBHeader(file_output, dib_header);
    writePixelsBMP(file_output, dib_header->width, dib_header->height, &pArr);
    printf("no errors");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: This isn't the kind of question we can answer here. We expect specific questions, not vague requests for guidance. This isn't an interactive discussion forum.

Comment: A small review of the code: There's just no need to allocate the BMP or DIB headers dynamically. Define them as non-pointer structure objects, and use the pointer-to operator `&` to get pointers when needed.

Comment: On another note, the character `'0'` is different from the number `0`. Please take some time to think about that for `fwrite("0", sizeof(char),padding, file)`. That write-call will also go out of bounds of the string if `padding` is larger than `2`.

Comment: Ok, you are right @Barmar, I rewrote my question to be more specific. My BMP and DIB header read and write work perfect. I can make the change but I am focused on getting my program to operate as intended first.

Comment: I also tried putting 0 and also tried putting '0' in the first argument for fwrite there but I got an error both times.

Comment: The padding required for each row of pixels depends on the size of the row in bits, not the size of the row in pixels.

Comment: would it just be %4 then?

Comment: I am focusing my efforts on the readpixelsbmp function right now and the lines                          
                                                                                                                                
`fread((*pArr)[i][j]->b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
fread((*pArr)[i][j]->r, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
fread((*pArr)[i][j]->g, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);`                                
give an error of: "passing argument 1 of 'fread' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]"
I tried casting but that crashed the program

Comment: Online it says to fix the "passing argument 1 of 'fread' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]" error you have to use & at the front. But that causes the program to crash. Am I doing something that I should not be doing with that line of code? I get no warning messages.